# Swift UI Test Static Text Value

Tags: swift, swift2, ui-testing

I have a label that gets its text assigned after a certain action happens, and I want to test that the text it has been assigned is correct with a UI test.

I am getting the XCUIElement with 
 .descendantsMatchingType(.StaticText).elementBoundByIndex(UInt(3))

The element is a staticText, and the element.value is not returning anything useful, and I'm unable to find another way of getting any sort of useful value from the staticText, besides the debugDescription. However, it says in the docs that the debugDescription is unreliable and should not be used for the actual tests.

How can I verify that this label has the correct text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered with a recent update to `XCUIElement`; there is now a `label` property that gets the text from a `.StaticText` element.

Comment: The label property returns the Accessibility label name, not the value of the value of the UILabel text.